# Maintaining cookies between HTTP requests sent by Android Apps

Tags: java, android, authentication, mobile, cookies

I'm building an Android app to provide the functionality of a website on android phones.

People are required to login, and they remain logged in using cookies, allowing them to do things under their own account. All the code for logging in/authentication has been done for the website, and I'm now writing an Android app to do the same thing.

My question is, if the Android app sends a HTTP request to the PHP server, and the server in return sets some cookies (to show that the user has logged on), would these cookies remain set on the Android app during all future HTTP requests to the server?

Or, do I need to work out a new authentication scheme for android, e.g passing a special token to the app on user login, and the app providing this token during all future requests to authenticate the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [CookieManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/CookieManager.html) and [CookieStore](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/CookieStore.html) To save Cookies.

> CookieManager will store cookies of every incoming HTTP response into CookieStore, and retrieve cookies for every outgoing HTTP request.Expired HttpCookies should be removed from this store by themselves.

You would use this with the [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) Class.

Comment: `get(URI uri) Retrieves cookies that match the specified URI` does that mean I will need to make two HTTP requests, first one to check if the user's login info is correct, then second to get the cookies?

Comment: I've not worked directly with the Cookie Manager I'm afraid but a collegue suggest following the patterns in the HttpURLConnection docs http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Answer (score 3):

Once You logined in App,you should save token in [SharedPrefrences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).And you can use in each Http Request later.Even when app is Restart you have that token.So SharedPredPrefrence is better for that.

Comment: but this means I will have to re-program the authentication code on the server. If there was a way to use cookies instead, that would be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

once you logged in put inside the **SharedPreferences**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("userName", "Rock");
editor.putString("token", "token@123");
```

get from the **SharedPreferences**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
String username = sharedPreferences.getString("userName", "");
String token = sharedPreferences.getString("token", "");
```